# select item of a Select box by its item number in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I select item of a Select box by its item number in jQuery?

```
<select id="selectbox" style="width: 220px;">
  <option value="Option 1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="Option 2">Option 2</option>
</select>
```

Like:

```
$("#selectbox").val() = $("#selectbox").Item[0].val();
```

I mean I want to toggle item to set it by its number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.val()` is a function so you cannot assign a value to it, you need to use the setter version of `.val()` to set an input element's value

You can access the first option's value using the index value

```
var $select = $("#selectbox");
$select.val($select.children().first().val())
//$select.val($select.children().eq(0).val())
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/AMW7b)

Comment: One question, do I need to set a var for it? Is $("#selectbox").val($("#selectbox").children().first().val()) fine?

Comment: @ComputerUser yes it is fine but since the selector is used twice it is better to cache the the element

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#selectbox").val($("#selectbox option:nth-child(0)").val());
```

Where 0 can be any number, of course

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to make this into a plugin.

```
;(function($){
  $.fn.setByOptionIndex = function( idx ){
    return this.each(function(){
      var $select = $(this);
      $select.val( $select.find('option').eq(idx - 1).val() );
    });
  }
})(jQuery);
```

Then just use it with:

```
$('select').setByOptionIndex(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

To me, this would be the clearest approach:

```
$("#selectbox option").eq(1).prop('selected',true);
```

Note, that the parameter of `eq()` function is treated like you would access an array. So the second element is `eq(1)`

Answer (score 0):

using javascript:

```
var select=document.getElementById("selectbox")
var options=select.getElementsByTagName("option")
select.value=options[0].innerHTML
```